# How to pass data to INPUT HIDE from heredoc in Oracle?

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus, heredoc

I'm not able to pass data meant to be user input (passwords are hidden) to oracle scripts. My idea was to automate the development deployments using predefined user input. Please see the following example:

test.sh:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba @$1 <<EOF
foo
bar
baz
EOF
```

test.sql:

```
SET DEFINE ON
ACCEPT STR1 PROMPT '1: '
ACCEPT STR2 PROMPT '2: '
ACCEPT STR3 PROMPT '3: '
PROMPT Got: &&STR1 &&STR2 &&STR3
```

$ ./test.sh test.sql

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

1: 2: 3: Got: foo bar baz
```

Everything looks fine until the input is hidden.

test_hide.sql:

```
SET DEFINE ON
ACCEPT STR1 PROMPT '1: '
ACCEPT STR2 HIDE PROMPT '2: '
ACCEPT STR3 PROMPT '3: '
PROMPT Got: &&STR1 &&STR2 &&STR3
```

$ ./test.sh test_hide.sql

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

1: 2:
3: Got: foo  bar
```

Is there a way to pass data to `ACCEPT ... HIDE` statement or I will need to rewrite the code?

Comment: Why do you want to use `HIDE` when the first version without it already is silent when reading from a heredoc?

Comment: @Socowi these scripts are maintained both for manual and automated deployments (and designed for the manual ones which are not silent) and I would not want to create a separate version if there is a way to handle this properly.